# Using gdal_translate to remove 4th band from command line

Tags: gdal, translate

I have quite a few geotiff files that I need to process with gdal_translate to remove the 4th (alpha) band. They are all in the same directory (for example, /imagery).

The original names are in the format m_3607604_ne_18_1_20160723_20160928b.tif, and after processing multiple files, output the new name in the same directory but with *c.tif. The examples I've tried keep throwing errors. I can run one file at a time successfully, using the below from a command prompt:

gdal_translate -b 1 -b 2 -b 3 m_3607604_ne_18_1_20160723_20160928b.tif m_3607604_ne_18_1_20160723_20160928c.tif

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem is not GIS specific but if you are on Windows try something like this:

```
for %i in (*.tif) DO gdal_translate -b 1 -b 2 -b 3 %~ni.tif %~ni_c.tif
```

If does not work exactly as you want because is takes

```
m_3607604_ne_18_1_20160723_20160928b.tif
```

and outputs

```
m_3607604_ne_18_1_20160723_20160928b_c.tif
```

You can rename the files afterwards. Myself I would write the result into a virtual VRT file, or if i would create new TIFF files I would create them as tiled and compressed, but you did not ask that.